# Ways of speeding up THREE.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js, webgl

I am writing a simple minecraft clone in THREE.js.

However, the result is very laggy.

I am using box geometry for the voxels, but I need to remove blocks when they are broken and need to use mouse picking.

I have heard that joining geometries speeds it up but as far as I am aware, this means that you cannot remove any of the voxels or use mouse picking.

What are the other ways of speeding up in THREE.js?

Comment: You should only have the visible blocks rendered, and the others in data storage (like how it is done in real Minecraft; only the externally visible vertices of blocks are rendered, that's why there are things known as xray texture packs, take a look at it and you'll see what I mean, there are cave systems visible because there are blocks that are exposed to the world).

Comment: I have a suspicion that using THREE.js geometry is not fast enough even with cpu help with visibility culling. You need to prepare to draw something like 5K planes (not cubes) every frame and those data probably need to be updated every frame. If you dont need to support infinite worlds/ your world is static then your best hope is to combine your world into one big mesh (in THREE i believe that is BufferGeometry) and come up with a way to update a portion of that mesh when you need to change a voxel. But at that point you might as well just do it with WebGL directly.

Comment: If you are ok with doing it without THREE.js I can give you some pointers on how to do it with webGL only as I have been working on a voxel engine as a side project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a box per voxel (making one draw call per voxel) will be too slow on any machine even if you wrote it in assembly language.

You need to build a mesh for every section of your world. As in divide the world into 48x48x48 unit chunks and build one mesh that contains all the voxels in that area. When the user edits a box you edit the mesh (the vertices) rather than remove a Box object.